# How to extract videos info of a huge channel using python youtube-dl?

Tags: python, youtube, youtube-dl

I'm using the following code to extract videos info (without downloading):

```
import youtube_dl

with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL({}) as ydl:
    result = ydl.extract_info(
        'https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCIG1k8umaCIIrujZPzZPIMA',
        download=False
    )
```

The above code is working for a small channel (100 videos) but for a huge channel (1000 videos) it shows `DownloadError: ERROR: Unable to download webpage: HTTP Error 429: Too Many Requests` after 200 videos.

I think it should wait a while every 100 videos for example.

How to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

dirty hack

modify the logic [here](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/blob/49c5293014bc11ec8c009856cd63cffa6296c1e1/youtube_dl/YoutubeDL.py#L1781) (youtube-dl) or [here](https://github.com/yt-dlp/yt-dlp/blob/a63ff77e22d2bb5fe0044dae685a1d2b5140fbbc/yt_dlp/YoutubeDL.py#L3222) (yt-dlp) from

```
if self._num_downloads exceeds max_downloads, then
    abort
```

to

```
if self._num_downloads is divisible by 100, then
    wait for a while
```

then you

```py
result = ydl.extract_info('https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCIG1k8umaCIIrujZPzZPIMA',
                           download=True)
```

beware that this will NOT work if you pass `download=False`